# Facing parse error while converting below mentioned ".xsd" to JAXB

Tags: java, rad

I'm facing parse error while converting below mentioned `.xsd` to `JAXB`.

Here is the error message:

```
Errors occurred during xjc.
    java.lang.Throwable:
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.jws22.v85.command.XjcCommand.runCodeXJC(Unknown Source)`enter code here`
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.jws22.v85.command.XjcCommand$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Unknown Source)
Error in parsing file:/D:/ticket165%20workspace/MetLife-GroupProfile-Services/GroupProfile.xsd.
    com.ibm.jtc.jax.istack.SAXParseException2: Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.xjc.generator.bean.ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.populate(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.xjc.generator.bean.PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.populate(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.jws22.v85.command.XjcDriverWrapper.execute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.jws22.v85.command.XjcCommand.runCodeXJC(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.jws22.v85.command.XjcCommand$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my `GroupProfile.xsd` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="subscrNmConsentStmt" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ShowEnrollmentTelephone" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ProductIdCardInd" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ShortName" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="MetOnlineGrpExp" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="priorityOrder" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="locked" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="Live" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="helpText" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="AlternateNames">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="Status">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" ref="SetupStatus"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ApprovalStatus"/>
        <xsd:choice>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" ref="ActiveDate"/>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" ref="LiveDate"/>
        </xsd:choice>
        <xsd:choice>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" ref="DisplayProduct"/>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" ref="Live"/>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="available" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="presentInitialInd" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ShowClaimsForm" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="subscriptionId" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="AlertEob" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ProductFormsInd">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="ShowClaimsForm"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ShowClaimsTelephone"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ClaimsTelephoneNumber"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ShowClaimsInitiationUrl"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ShowEnrollmentForms"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ShowEnrollmentTelephone"/>
        <xsd:element ref="EnrollmentTelephoneNumber"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ShowEnrollmentUrl"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ShowBeneficiaryForms"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ShowBeneficiaryTelephone"/>
        <xsd:element ref="BeneficiaryTelephoneNumber"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ShowBeneficiaryUrl"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ShowOtherForms"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="CertifiedProviderSearchInd" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="HoursOfOperationList">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="HoursOfOperation"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="EmailName" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="Names">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="GeneralName"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PortalBannerName"/>
        <xsd:element ref="EmailName"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="EndTime" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="MPEIndicator" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="AddressType" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="StartTime" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ClaimsPhoneNum" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ShowClaimsTelephone" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ApprovalStatus" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="EsigPasswordInd" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="GNA" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="consentStmtReq" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="enableForEligible" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="Subscription">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="productCode"/>
        <xsd:element ref="name"/>
        <xsd:element ref="subscriptionId"/>
        <xsd:element ref="enabled"/>
        <xsd:element ref="locked"/>
        <xsd:element ref="subscriptionMethodType"/>
        <xsd:element ref="autoSubscriptionType"/>
        <xsd:element ref="presentInitialInd"/>
        <xsd:element ref="presentSubsequentInd"/>
        <xsd:element ref="subsequentInterval"/>
        <xsd:element ref="groupEmailVarTxt"/>
        <xsd:element ref="groupEmailTemplateId"/>
        <xsd:element ref="offerSubscriptionId"/>
        <xsd:element ref="helpText"/>
        <xsd:element ref="offerText"/>
        <xsd:element ref="maintainText"/>
        <xsd:element ref="indvUnsubscrEmailTemplateId"/>
        <xsd:element ref="indvUnsubscrEmailVarTxt"/>
        <xsd:element ref="apprTextIniOfferPg"/>
        <xsd:element ref="apprTextUpdProfilePg"/>
        <xsd:element ref="subscrNmConsentStmt"/>
        <xsd:element ref="priorityOrder"/>
        <xsd:element ref="displayName"/>
        <xsd:element ref="enableForEligible"/>
        <xsd:element ref="consentStmtReq"/>
        <xsd:element ref="provideCntctInfo"/>
        <xsd:element ref="enableForDependent"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="ReturnToSiteURL" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ProductLOBOrder" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="BenefitsUrlSpecInstr" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="indvUnsubscrEmailTemplateId">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="enabled" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="AddressLineTwo" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="LongName" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="GroupProfile">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="Names"/>
        <xsd:element ref="Status"/>
        <xsd:element ref="CustomerSegment"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ServiceUnit"/>
        <xsd:element ref="CdfNumber"/>
        <xsd:element ref="TestGroupInd"/>
        <xsd:element ref="MPEIndicator"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ReturnToSiteURL"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PortalOptions"/>
        <xsd:element ref="Registration"/>
        <xsd:element ref="AlternateNames"/>
        <xsd:element ref="Products"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="groupNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="PublicAccess" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ProductContact">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="ContactUrlLinkText"/>
        <xsd:element ref="FaxNumber"/>
        <xsd:element ref="BenefitsUrl"/>
        <xsd:element ref="BenefitsUrlSpecInstr"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ServicePhoneLeaderText"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ServicePhoneParagraph"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ServicePhoneNum"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ServicePhoneHoursOfOperation"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ClaimsPhoneNum"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ClaimsPhoneHoursOfOperation"/>
        <xsd:element ref="LiveChatPhoneNum"/>
        <xsd:element ref="LiveChatHoursOfOperation"/>
        <xsd:element ref="GeneralCorrespondence"/>
        <xsd:element ref="Billing"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PaymentOrDepositWithStub"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PaymentOrDepositWithoutStub"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="CustomerSegment">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="GNA"/>
        <xsd:element ref="GRO"/>
        <xsd:element ref="SBC"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="maintainText" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="enableForDependent" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ProdVarParamLabel2">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="Billing">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="AddressType"/>
        <xsd:element ref="AddressLineOne"/>
        <xsd:element ref="AddressLineTwo"/>
        <xsd:element ref="City"/>
        <xsd:element ref="State"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PostalCode"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PostalExtension"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="ShowBeneficiaryTelephone" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ProductCode" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ProdVarParamLabel3">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="ProdVarParamLabel4">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="PrintSignMailInd" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="AddressLineOne" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="PaymentOrDepositWithoutStub">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="AddressType"/>
        <xsd:element ref="AddressLineOne"/>
        <xsd:element ref="AddressLineTwo"/>
        <xsd:element ref="City"/>
        <xsd:element ref="State"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PostalCode"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PostalExtension"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="LiveChatHoursOfOperation">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="HoursOfOperationList"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="displayName" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="State" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="groupEmailTemplateId">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="PortalOptions">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="MetLifeBranding"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ShowLifeEventsAdviceInd"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ShowMetlifeDotComInd"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ShowLiveChatInd"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PromptToWebChatInd"/>
        <xsd:element ref="MetOnlineGrpExp"/>
        <xsd:element ref="EnableClickTale"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="GeneralName" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="PostalCode" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="productCode" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="IndividualAccess" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ShowLiveChatInd" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ProdVarParamValue2">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="ProdVarParamValue3">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="ProdVarParamValue4">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="GeneralCorrespondence">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="AddressType"/>
        <xsd:element ref="AddressLineOne"/>
        <xsd:element ref="AddressLineTwo"/>
        <xsd:element ref="City"/>
        <xsd:element ref="State"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PostalCode"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PostalExtension"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="PortalBannerName" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="Products">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="Product"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="groupEmailVarTxt">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="ShowBeneficiaryForms" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="City" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ShowMetlifeDotComInd" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ProductSetId" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="TranslationInd" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ServicePhoneLeaderText" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="KeyIdentifierField">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="offerSubscriptionId" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="PostalExtension" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ServicePhoneParagraph" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="EligibilityRequirement" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ClaimsTelephoneNumber">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="GroupAccess" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="FaxNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="EnrollmentTelephoneNumber">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="offerText" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="PaymentOrDepositWithStub">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="AddressType"/>
        <xsd:element ref="AddressLineOne"/>
        <xsd:element ref="AddressLineTwo"/>
        <xsd:element ref="City"/>
        <xsd:element ref="State"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PostalCode"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PostalExtension"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="ProductDescription" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ShowEnrollmentUrl" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ShowEnrollmentForms" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="SsoRequired" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="CdfNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="presentSubsequentInd" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="TreatAsParticipating" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="SetupStatus" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="TestGroupInd" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="apprTextUpdProfilePg" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ShowLifeEventsAdviceInd" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ContactUrlLinkText" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="subscriptionMethodType" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ClaimsPhoneHoursOfOperation">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="HoursOfOperationList"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="ServiceUnit" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ServicePhoneHoursOfOperation">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="HoursOfOperationList"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="IdCardOrderInd" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ShowClaimsInitiationUrl" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="GRO" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="autoSubscriptionType" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ShowBeneficiaryUrl" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="provideCntctInfo" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="MyAcctProdSpecificCustNum">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="GsmSessionParticipation" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="apprTextIniOfferPg" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="Product">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="ProductCode"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ExternalIdentifier"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ProductSetId"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ShortName"/>
        <xsd:element ref="LongName"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ProductCategory"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ProductDescription"/>
        <xsd:element ref="Status"/>
        <xsd:element ref="EligibilityRequirement"/>
        <xsd:element ref="GroupAccess"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PublicAccess"/>
        <xsd:element ref="IndividualAccess"/>
        <xsd:element ref="TreatAsParticipating"/>
        <xsd:element ref="SsoRequired"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ClaimsIntake"/>
        <xsd:element ref="UisProductId"/>
        <xsd:element ref="MyAcctProdSpecificCustNum"/>
        <xsd:element ref="KeyIdentifierField"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ProdVarParamLabel2"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ProdVarParamValue2"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ProdVarParamLabel3"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ProdVarParamValue3"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ProdVarParamLabel4"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ProdVarParamValue4"/>
        <xsd:element ref="GsmSessionParticipation"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ClaimsTelephoneNumber"/>
        <xsd:element ref="CertifiedProviderSearchInd"/>
        <xsd:element ref="EsigPasswordInd"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PrintSignMailInd"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ProductIdCardInd"/>
        <xsd:element ref="TranslationInd"/>
        <xsd:element ref="IdCardOrderInd"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ForeignProviderName"/>
        <xsd:element ref="AlertEob"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ProductLOB"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ProductLOBOrder"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ProductContact"/>
        <xsd:element ref="Subscriptions"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ProductFormsInd"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="indvUnsubscrEmailVarTxt">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="SBC" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="Subscriptions">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="Subscription"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="Registration">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="subsequentInterval" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="LiveDate" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="LiveChatPhoneNum" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="HoursOfOperation">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="StartDay"/>
        <xsd:element ref="EndDay"/>
        <xsd:element ref="StartTime"/>
        <xsd:element ref="EndTime"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="typeCode" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="productCode" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="hrsAvailSeqNum" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="EndDay" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ClaimsIntake" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="BeneficiaryTelephoneNumber">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="UisProductId">
    <xsd:complexType/>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="EnableClickTale" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="DisplayProduct" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ProductCategory" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ServicePhoneNum" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ForeignProviderName" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ProductLOB" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="PromptToWebChatInd" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="MetLifeBranding" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="BenefitsUrl" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ExternalIdentifier" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ActiveDate" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="StartDay" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="ShowOtherForms" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: I think it's saying that you have the same type defined twice. But I am on a mobile so I can't actually see the issue in the xsd